# GWTBootstrap: Programmatically add Navlink to Dropdown?

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to add a navlink to a dropdown in a navbar.  I am doing this programmatically.  So far I am not having any luck and nothing is shown except a small empty drop down.  what am I missing?  Is there an issue with doing it this way?

ui.xml:

```
<b:ResponsiveNavbar position="TOP" scrollspy="false" inverse="true">
        <b:Brand href="#">MyApp</b:Brand>
         <b:Nav alignment="RIGHT">
    <b:Dropdown ui:field="login" rightDropdown="true" icon="SIGNIN" iconSize="LARGE"></b:Dropdown>
    </b:Nav>
        <b:NavCollapse>
            <b:Nav ui:field="nav" />
        </b:NavCollapse>
    </b:ResponsiveNavbar>
```

MyCode.java:

```
     @UiField
     Dropdown login;


                                            login.setText(userName);
                    NavLink signout=new NavLink();
                    signout.setText("Signout");
                    signout.setIcon(IconType.SIGNOUT);
                    login.add(signout);
                    signout.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                            //TODO signout implementation
                        }

                    });
```